# getting one div to overlap another - jsfiddle created

Tags: html, z-index

I need to have the white "content area" on top of the black area in the following...

http://jsfiddle.net/vUrhY/

I played around with z-indexes and margins, but can't seem to get it to work.  Basically the black will be under the white and you would be able to see the white content edges on top of the black background.  Thank you.

```
body{background-color:#999;}.div-main{height:200px;width:400px;z-index:1000;background:#fff;padding:30px 0 30px 0;max-width:1000px;margin:0 auto;}
.footer_filler{background-color:#000; width:100%; height:300px;z-index:-1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Study up on the `position` style rule in CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fposition

Specifically, you can look into [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fposition#Absolute_positioning) or [relative positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fposition#Relative_positioning).

Comment: Thank you.  position:relative took care of it with margin-bottom:-75px; on the top layer.

Comment: @breinhart - you're welcome. please upvote answers that help, or even mark it as an answer. those points are the currency that keeps the SO economy afloat.

Comment: I haven't been on here in a while and I tried to up vote your answer, but I need a rep of 15 to do that...seems silly to me if the answer helped, but that's how it works.